# Set zoom level on google map in android

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

I need to show my current and target locations on google map with max zoom level. Here is my code to show both locations with max zoom. But its zooming to center of both locations and my locations are going out of the sight. I want my both locations should be in view bounds and set the zoom as maximum as possible. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_marker);  

    overlayList = mapView.getOverlays();
    myMap = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myMap.enableMyLocation();   

    mapController = mapView.getController(); 

    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (targetLatitude * 1E6), (int) (targetLongitude * 1E6));

    mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(((int) (targetLatitude * 1E6) + (int) (currentLatitude * 1E6))/2, ((int) (targetLongitude * 1E6) + (int) (curLongitude * 1E6))/2 )); 
    mapController.zoomToSpan((int)(targetLatitude - currentLatitude), (int)(targetLongitude - curLongitude));

    mapController.setZoom(12);

    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint,"xxx", "yyyy");

    CustomPinpoint customPinpoint = new CustomPinpoint(mapMarker, this);
    customPinpoint.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);

    overlayList.clear();
    overlayList.add(myMap);
    overlayList.add(customPinpoint);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (GeoPoint point : points) {
        minLat = Math.min(point.getLatitudeE6(), minLat);
        minLong = Math.min(point.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
        maxLat = Math.max(point.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat);
        maxLong = Math.max(point.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong);
    }

    MapController controller = view.getController();
    controller.zoomToSpan(
                       Math.abs(minLat - maxLat), Math.abs(minLong - maxLong));
    controller.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat) / 2,
        (maxLong + minLong) / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the zoom level and animate to the geopoint where you want your marker to be fixed.